# Get a list of all the sheet tab names from a Google spreadsheet and put the names into another spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet that contains around 50 to 60 sheets. I am trying to get the names of all those sheets, and put them into another spreadsheet.

So far I have written the following code

```
function myfunction(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("abck12345");
  var sheetCount = ss.getSheets().length;
  var  i=0;

  var sheetlist;

  while(i<sheetCount){
    sheetlist = ss.getSheets()[i];
    Logger.log(sheetlist);
  }

}
```

While executing this i am getting an error "Exceeded maximum execution time"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not incrementing i. A better way to do would be as follows:

```
function myfunction(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1cmUWU_nbE6idJUmpNtKnhq0KUekVXnW9OYVZr93TSNs");
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var  i;

  for(i in sheets){
    Logger.log(sheets[i].getName())
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is more efficient to get all the sheets at once.  Your code is getting all the sheets on every loop.  This code gets all the sheet names and puts them into a new spreadsheet:

```
function myfunction() {
  var allSheets,i,sheetCount,sheetlist,sheetName,ss,
      targetSh,targetSS,thisSheet;

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("abck12345");
  targetSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("999999");

  allSheets = ss.getSheets();
  sheetCount = allSheets.length;

  sheetlist = [];

  for (i=0;i<sheetCount;i++) {
    thisSheet = allSheets[i];
    sheetName = thisSheet.getName();

    sheetlist.push([sheetName]);//Put an inner array of each sheet tab name into 
    //an outer array named sheetlist
    //Creates a 2D array for setting the values later
  }

  Logger.log(sheetlist);

  targetSh = targetSS.getSheetByName('target sheet tab name');
  targetSh.getRange(targetSh.getLastRow()+1, 1, sheetlist.length, sheetlist[0].length).setValues(sheetlist);
}
```